# De-awkwardize middle G trill on recorder

Tags: recorder, trills, ornaments

The third movement of Bach's second Brandenburg Concerto calls for multiple trills on the middle G in F. The fingering is highly awkward because it is right between two registers and I am looking for an easier method to obtain the trill. I am aware of playing G with the left digits 2, 3, and 4 and the right digits 2, 3, 4, and 5, but trilling with my right fifth and fourth digits is just about as difficult as well. Is there any alternate method for the trill?

Comment: Can you provide an example in the score?

Comment: [Here is the recorder part](http://petrucci.mus.auth.gr/imglnks/usimg/d/dd/IMSLP37609-PMLP82078-Bach-BWV1047.Flute.pdf). It is on page 6, the beginning of the third movement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kenneth Wollitz in his *The Recorder Book* suggests using the alternative G fingering you describe, and trilling on your right third finger.  I just tried it, and it seems pretty reasonable.

Comment: That would produce a trill from G# to A, no?

Comment: No, that's not what happened when I tried it, I got G to A.

Comment: Okay, tried it again, how that I don't have to worry about waking the neighbors, and I'm getting better luck with G= 1 2 3, 4 5 6 /7 (half holing 7) and trilling 6, while keeping 7 half holed.  Trilling on a forth finger that way is not entirely non-awkward, but at least you're not moving your whole hand for the trill.

Comment: Whoops, your original fingering actually works fine. I was thinking you were saying trilling with the right ring finger (4). Trilling the middle finger (3) works great.